# What is wrong with my Camellia?

Tags: plant-health

What is wrong with my Camellia?

It hasn't been looking too happy recently but I just returned from a 2 week holiday and it looks like this (I live in London, uk and it should get sun most of the day)

[image: Help me]

Comment: London in the UK?

Comment: Yes. London UK. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like drought. I don't know where you are in the world, so its hard to judge what your weather might have been like while you were away, and I also can't judge whether this plant is sited in sun all day or not. If it has half a day's sun, the temperature was up, and no-one was coming to water, that would explain this - even if they were coming, this one has been missed.

UPDATED ANSWER

You've said you're in the UK, so its defnitely drought - there's been some good weather while you were away. I suspect it needed a bigger pot too, and if its potbound, it would have dried out more quickly. The only thing you can do now is cut it back by a half to two thirds of its height, move it somewhere shady and keep it well watered. You might get some regrowth, you might not, depends how dry the roots got. A plant in drought will sacrifice its leaves first, but that doesn't necessarily mean the roots are dead, only time will tell I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Bamboo, I live in London. Is it recoverable do you think?

Comment: @Joe - in the UK?

Comment: PS is drought the only potential theory? I only ask because all the other plants in the garden that are in pots look healthy. You are right though that this plant probably needs a bigger pot.

Comment: @Joe I.m convinced its drought - it needed repotting, which means there was more root than soil in the pot, so there wasn't enough soil to hold any moisture for any length of time. Had it been in the shade, you might have got away with it, but I'm not sure you would even then - two  weeks is a long time for a potbound plant, especially an evergreen one. If there was any rain at all (and there wasn't, really, I live in London too) the foliage would have kept it out of the pot anyway.